# Compute Modulo exponentiation with prime powers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, number-theory

The problem is to find x such that

$$x = M^d \mod p^2$$, where M and d are large numbers, and p is
a large prime. Ideally we only want to compute $M^d\mod p$ and then use the result to further figure out $x$.

I know how it can be done if M^d is small, e.g. using [The Lifting Theorem](http://www.cs.xu.edu/math/math302/04f/PolyCongruences.pdf) 
However, in the problem mentioned, we do not want to compute M^d completely. So
it is not clear that this theorem is useful.

Comment: Just compute $M^d \bmod{p^2}$; what's the problem?

Comment: @fkraiem Computing $M^d \mod p^2$ takes much more time than $M^d \mod p$.